# How to make log parsing faster for large text files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, textbox

I have large (500,000 line) log files that I parse through for specified sections. When found the sections are printed to a Text widget. Even if I cut the readlines down to the last 50,000 lines it takes upwards of a minute or longer to finish.

```
with open(i, "r") as f:
    r = f.readlines()
    r = r[-50000:]
    start = 0
    for line in r:
        if 'Start section' in line:
            if start == 1:
                cpfotxt.insert('end', line + "\n", 'hidden')
            start = 1
        if 'End section' in line:
            start = 0
            cpfotxt.insert('end', line + "\n")
        if start == 1:
            cpfotxt.insert('end', line + "\n")
f.close()
```

Any way to do this faster?

Comment: Does it have to be a Text widget?  What do you use ```hidden``` for?

Comment: Maybe accumulate all the lines in a list then write them all at once.  Or implement the [ListView widget](http://effbot.org/zone/wck-4.htm)

Comment: @wwii I needed something that I could write to and interact with using tags, font, etc. Text widget seemed to fit the need.

Comment: hidden is for minimizing sections of the text widget. The delays were there before that was added.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to read it in chunks.

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        <do something with line>
```

A more clear approach that can be applied for you:

```
def readInChunks(fileObj, chunkSize=2048):
    """
    Lazy function to read a file piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 2kB.
    """
    while True:
        data = fileObj.read(chunkSize)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data

f = open('bigFile')
for chuck in readInChunks(f):
    do_something(chunk)
```

Comment: If a chunk contains a partial line, at the beginning or the end, how do you handle it.

Comment: Well, in the first example you could check if the last or the first is a partial line. If so, you can read one more line until it completes. In the first example, there shouldn't be partial lines at the begging.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use **seek** to skip over a lot of lines.  However, this requires that you have *some* idea of how large the last 50K lines might be.  Instead of reading through all the early lines, jump close to the end:

```
with ... as f:
    f.seek(-50000 * 80)
    # insert your processing here
```